# how to measure time saved by using precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdafx.h

I have a Visual C++ solution with about 15 projects that takes over 30 minutes to build.
It is a large solution and we are doing all sorts of bad things such as including windows api header all over the place instead of putting them in stdafx.h

Before i go in and move those headers to stdafx.h i want to measure how much time my effort woudl save. I was thinking about doing rebuild before my change and after my change but i precompiled header starts to pay off on 2nd incremental build, not rebuild as it would clean pch file as well.

any way to measure this?

Comment: I have a Visual C++ solution with more than 300 projects, and it takes ~50 minutes to build. We use precompiled headers everywhere, and API headers as well as standard libraries are included from PCH only. Do the math yourself. Also the assumption that it "starts to pay off on 2nd incremental build" is wrong.

Comment: Precompiled header reduces full rebuild time in any case. The point here that .pch file is built once per project, and the all project files are compiled using this header.

Comment: In our case, using precompiled headers changed the system rebuild time from 30 min to 10 min approximately.

Comment: The performance will depend on whether you have the same precompiled header for each project or a different one. You run into the Law Of Diminishing Returns quite quickly if you start to move lots of things into the PCH file. It's difficult to predict the benefit you'll get until you try it. It's best to try it on one project first and measure the results. Bear in mind that caching will affect the measurement (ie a second compile will always be faster if you do it straight after). If you have a tool to eat up spare RAM then that may help clear the cache.

Comment: You're not losing anything by using PCH. In fact, the gains skyrocket in cases where an internal change to a library is needed. PCH may save you time parsing all the dependencies upon successive builds of a project.